# UWP: how to style my ListBoxItem and add some triggers

Tags: uwp, listbox, styles

I have this `Style`:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor" Fill="#FFBADDE9" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor2" Fill="#FFBADDE9" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1"/>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And i want to add some color changed for `Mouse Over` and `Selected` and i am very confuse compare to `WPF` triggers.

Answer (score 1):

ListBox is obsolete, instead use a ListView with either a vertical or horizontal layout orientation.

To change the base Panel, you have to add a node inside your listview like this

> ```
> <ListView>
> <ListView.ItemsPanel>
>   <ItemsPanelTemplate>
>      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" /><!-- Or vertical-->
>    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
> </ListView.ItemsPanel>
> </Listview
> ```

This is the fastest way of editing the style of the actual container that wraps around each item in a ListView (it is called ListViewItem) :

> ```
> <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
>                         <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
>                             <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
>                             <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
>                             <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>
>                             <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
>                         </Style>
> </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
> ```

As far as the other part of your question and in in regards to triggers, triggers and especially custom triggers and their use is kinda meh in uwp, in order to achieve such functionality as a color change based to the Pointer state, You can do it very simply by editing the default style sheet, listview is a kinda complicated to in terms of styling, but you only need to edit the default ListViewItem style, the same thing i talked above, this time it will be a complete dive-in into its stylin.

The ListViewItem style is conveniently found
here

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299136.aspx

It looks like this

> ```
> <!-- Default style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewItem -->
> <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
> <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
> <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
> <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
> <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
> <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
> <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
> <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,0,12,0"/>
> <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
> <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
> <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinWidth}"/>
> <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinHeight}"/>
> <Setter Property="Template">
>   <Setter.Value>
>     <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
>       <ListViewItemPresenter
>           ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
>           SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="True"
>           CheckBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
>           CheckBoxBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
>           DragBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}"
>           DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}"
>           FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAltHighBrush}"
>           FocusSecondaryBorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"
>           PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}"
>           PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListLowBrush}"
>           PointerOverForeground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"
>           SelectedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush}"
>           SelectedForeground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"
>           SelectedPointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush}"
>           PressedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListMediumBrush}"
>           SelectedPressedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentHighBrush}"
>           DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}"
>           DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}"
>           ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
>           HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
>           VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
>           ContentMargin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
>           CheckMode="Inline"/>
>     </ControlTemplate>
>   </Setter.Value>
> </Setter>
> </Style>
> ```

In your case all you have to do is change the PointerOver and PointerOverSelected background values, after that give a x:Key value to your sheet and reference it like:

```
<ListView ItemContainerStyle={StaticResource YourKey}
```